# Why does web view crashes

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm calling a webpage in WKWebView but it always crashes when I launch the app, with this error message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value.

My code is below

```
let param = "https://myapp.mydomain.com/GameAPI/index.jsp?user=0202020767|0202020767"
let url = URL(string: param)
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

At this point the nil is pointing to this code:

```
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Comment: `|` is an invalid character, you must see which character the java server waits to then split the users id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @Kerberos the java server uses | to split it parameters i add

Comment: Ok, try to use this link: `https://myapp.mydomain.com/GameAPI/index.jsp?user=0202020767%70202020767`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that "`|`" character in the parameter is messing up your URL.

Try doing this:

```
let param = "user=0202020767|0202020767"
let escapedParam = param.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let fullURLString = "https://myapp.mydomain.com/GameAPI/index.jsp?\(escapedParam)"
if let url = URL(string: fullURLString) {
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
} else {
    Swift.print("url is nil for some reason")
}
```

Comment: it's not crashing anymore but the webview is always blank. I tried to print url and i had something like this https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.mydomain.com%2FGameAPI%2Findex.jsp%3Fuser=0202020767%7C0202020767

Comment: I modified my code to only escape the params.  Let's see that happens!

Comment: Your solution worked but I have to force unwrapped escapedParam. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because the url that you have tried to reach could not be resolved.

Also, you better use optional binding rather than forcing unwrap.

Here the code that you can check with valid url:

```
if let url = URL(string: "your url") {
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

} else {
   print("could not open url, it is nil")
}
```